# Solution of linear inequality

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

I have the following system of linear inequality on $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, $x_i \in \mathbb{R} \; \forall i$

$x_i - 2x_j < b \; \forall i, j$
The right hand side of the inequality ($b \in \mathbb{R}_+$) is fixed (and given) for all inequalities.

From simulation I can see that the only solution to this system of equation is when all $x_i$'s are equal. Is there a formal proof to show this ?

Comment: I'm confused. If say $b=4$ and $x_i=0,1$. then that's a perfectly good solution.

Comment: Basically it sums up to solving $x_i-2x_j<0$ if $b$ is the same for all the equations and since it is strictly positive. Maybe we are missing something, but an idea would be to show by contradiction that if a pair of those is not equal, then you may choose $x_i=3x_j$ for some $i,j$, which will invalidate the RHS. *Note: basically construct some $x$ that will provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have
some restriction on $b$.

Otherwise,
for any set of
$x_i$,
choose
$b > 3\max(|x_i|)
$.
Then
all the inequalities
hold.